# What is the alternative to CURLOPT_MUTE?

Tags: ftp, libcurl

I'm using libcurl as part of my software for implementing an FTP client. One thing that I must do before sending files to the FTP server is to make a connectivity check by listing the the content of the target directory (to make sure I can connect and the directory exists) as was suggested to me in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20274980/check-ftp-login-using-libcurl). The problem is I don't care about the output of the listing operation, all is care is whether the connectivity test passed or failed. In case it passed I get enormous amount of text which I'd like to discard. I'm using libcurl 7.33, however in 7.15 CURLOPT_MUTE was removed and I can't understand how to discard the listing output. Is there an alternative to CURLOPT_MUTE or any other idea how discard output from `curl_easy_perform`?

```
curl_easy_setopt(m_curl, CURLOPT_USERNAME, m_ftpUsername);
curl_easy_setopt(m_curl, CURLOPT_PASSWORD, m_ftpPassword);
curl_easy_setopt(m_curl, CURLOPT_URL, m_ftpUrl);
CURLcode res = curl_easy_perform(m_curl);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provide a CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION callback that simply ignores the data and returns the correct value!

BTW, MUTE never worked to "discard the listing output".

Answer (score 0):

Define a callback function

```
size_t callbackFunction(char *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *userdata)
{
    return size * nmemb;
}
```

And then

```
curl_easy_setopt(m_curl, CURLOPT_USERNAME, m_ftpUsername);
curl_easy_setopt(m_curl, CURLOPT_PASSWORD, m_ftpPassword);
curl_easy_setopt(m_curl, CURLOPT_URL, m_ftpUrl);
curl_easy_setopt(m_curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, callbackFunction);
CURLcode res = curl_easy_perform(m_curl);
curl_easy_setopt(m_curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, 0); // return using the default callback
```